# Authenticate Ionic 2 app with asp.net web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, ionic2

I'm using ASP.net Web API 2 as my Backend and an Ionic 2 app as my front end.

I'm using Microsoft's UserStore Manager in Authenticating my application.

It uses Token Based Authentication (Please forgive me if i'm using wrong namings i'm still new to this).

I was able to get a token via Postman and then use this token in the request headers like this "Bearer [token]" to get any data from my Web api.

[image: Getting the Token with Postman]

As you can see the Method is Post and the Content-Type is x-www-form-urlencoded.

doing this it generates an access_token and then I take this token use it in my headers to get what I need.

In my Ionic App I created an auth-service.ts with a public method called login()

```
  public login(credentials) {
if (credentials.username === null || credentials.password === null) {
  let error = this.alertController.create({
    title:'Lol',
    message:'incomplete credentials, Fill them up and come back',
    buttons: ['ok']
  });

  error.present();
}
else {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/token`,
    {
      grant_type:'password',
      username:credentials.username,
      password:credentials.password
    }).map(res => console.log(resolve(res.json())));
  });
}
```

}

And here is the Code in circles.ts that calls this method :

```
  login(){
let credentials = {
  username:"01286220336",
  password:"P@$$w0rd"
}
this.authService.login(credentials)
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(data => console.log(data));
```

}

My problem is when I call the Login Method in Circles.ts nothing happens I don't know why. I've been trying for 2 weeks but I just gave up.

Also I'm not sure if i'm implementing the login method in the authservice.ts right.

In the end I just need to obtain this Token somehow , if anyone could put me on the right way i'd be extremely thankful !!

Comment: the problem is the format .. you have to set the header of you login to send it in the right format (x-www-form-url encoded) beacuse default it send as json .. and you've to concat the username / password/ grant_type like .. username=xxxx&password=xxxx&grant_type=password

Comment: return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/token`,
        `username=${credentials.username}&password=${credentials.password}&grant_type=password`
        ).map(res => resolve(res.json()));
      });

Here's the new snippet , still returning nothing

Comment: wait you've to voverride the header of your post ..something like: this.http.post(${this.baseUrl}/token,username=${credentials.username}&password=${credentials.pass‌​word}&grant_type=pas‌​sword,{headers:{'Content-type:''x-www-form-urlencoded'}})

Comment: i have made an edit...the order was worng .... header is in the end

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing else part with following code.

```
else{
    let authObject = "username=xxxx&password=xxxx&grant_type=password";
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/token', authObject, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
           alert(JSON.stringify(res.json(), null, 4));
      });
}
```